# How to display data in an HTML table using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am trying to display the data I fetch from an API onto an HTML table. My code is below:

```
 <div class="container2">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TEAM</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>WON</th>
        <th>DRAW</th>
        <th>LOST</th>
        <th>POINTS</th>
        <th>SCORED</th>
        <th>CONCEDED</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
fetch("https://heisenbug-premier-league-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/premierleague/table", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "host",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
    }
}).then(
  response => {
    response.json().then(
      data =>{
       
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length > 0){
          var temp = "";
          
          data.forEach((x) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.team +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.played +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.win +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.draw +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.loss +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.goalsFor +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.goalsAgainst +"</td>";
            temp += "<td>"+ x.points +"</td>";
            temp += "</tr>"
          });
          
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
})
```

When this is is run the API is fetched and an object is successfully retrieved. However, it is not displaying in the table. I have checked console log and there are no errors.

Comment: Please do not post API keys and private URLs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `console.log(data)` actually logs? Doesn't need to be the whole thing, just enough to imply structure and data types

Comment: You should add a catch block that logs any errors.  Right now errors are not shown.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: Your `data` is an **object**, not an array. You want `data.records.forEach()`. This can be closed as a _typo_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` is an *Object*, it has not attribute `length`, and thus the condition becomes `false`.

However, the required data is supposedly in `data.records`. Simply changing that `if` condition to `data.records.length > 0` and instead of iterating over `data`, doing so over `data.records` fixes the issue.

```js
fetch("https://heisenbug-premier-league-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/premierleague/table", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "host",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "key",
    }
}).then(
    response => {
        response.json().then(
            data => {

                console.log(data);
                var temp = "";

                data.records.forEach((x) => {
                    temp += "<tr>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.team + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.played + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.win + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.draw + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.loss + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.goalsFor + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.goalsAgainst + "</td>";
                    temp += "<td>" + x.points + "</td>";
                    temp += "</tr>"
                });

                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += temp;
            }
        )
    })
```

```html
<div class="container2">
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>TEAM</th>
                <th>GP</th>
                <th>WON</th>
                <th>DRAW</th>
                <th>LOST</th>
                <th>POINTS</th>
                <th>SCORED</th>
                <th>CONCEDED</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @Phil, the data check is redundant, thus removed it from the snippet.

Comment: @Phil innerHTML would be left unset, which might be relevant if it had a previous value.

Comment: @user2740650 we can fix that one just by changing `innerHTML = temp` to `innerHTML += temp`.

Comment: @LakshayaU. Yes, the change will work but the OP's original code with fixes is simplest in terms of readability.